# Retrieve elements from two levels using AWS CLI 'describe-instances'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I would like to --query across multiple levels of the aws ec2 describe-instances API. For example, I would like to combine:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[ImageId, InstanceType, KeyName, State.Name, PublicIpAddress, NetworkInterfaces.Groups.GroupName]' --output json`

and fields such as OwnerId which are a level above Instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the top-level `OwnerId` by specifying it prior to `Instances[*]`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].[OwnerId,Instances[*].[ImageId, InstanceType, KeyName, State.Name, PublicIpAddress, NetworkInterfaces.Groups.GroupName]]' --output json
```

However, the fact that there is a one-to-many relationship to the instances means it will be returned at a higher level:

```
[
    [
        "123456789012", 
        [
            [
                "ami-48d38c2b", 
                "t2.micro", 
                "class", 
                "running", 
                "54.2.33.44", 
                null
            ]
        ]
    ], 
    [
        "123456789012", 
        [
            [
                "ami-f806349b", 
                "t2.small", 
                "class", 
                "running", 
                "54.1.22.33", 
                null
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

By the way, the `OwnerId` is merely the ID of the AWS Account that owns the resource, which in almost every case would be the same value.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax! I'm using this in a multi-account setting, and the OwnerId is useful. Appreciate it.